# arp across subnets which devices can be detected?

Tags: networking, ethernet, arp, discovery

i have some devices connected in the same physical network (LAN) but in different subnets. I want to detect them all with the ARP from my computer. My Computer is also in the same physical network but on a different subnet.
! The devices have no arp protocol installed (yet).

1. Is it possible to detect the devices (with or withour ARP installed on every device)?
2. If the devices have a MAC-address but no IP-address, can ARP still detect the machines?

Comment: [I'm not sure that you fully understand what ARP is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). You don't *install* the ARP protocol. Any device that has an IP stack on it will by definition implement the ARP protocol. Oh, and by the way, ARP is a broadcast protocol, meaning it won't cross subnet boundaries. An ARP request for a device on another subnet will give you the MAC address of the gateway to that network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. If the devices have an assigned IP address, they will respond to ARP queries. (It may take some effort to properly craft the ARP queries.)
2. No. If the devices don't have an assigned IP address, they will not respond to ARP queries.

Comment: Hi and thx. what do you mean by "craft the query". Is it not possible to broadcast all subnets (arp -a) in my case?

Comment: @Gobliins: What would go in the "target protocol address" field?

Comment: until now i would leave it blank. But maybe insert something like "255.255.255.255"

Comment: Then no device would respond.

Comment: you mean i would need information about the subnets? i.e. 192.168.x.x or 169.254.x.x

Comment: You would need some way to craft a query the device would respond to. Sending broadcast ARP queries for all 3 billion valid IP addresses is probably not practical. Knowing at least the subnets in use would help a lot.